# Python Regular expression for splitting mentions of two years appearing altogether

Tags: python, regex

I have the following case, where in my string I have improperly formatted mentions of the form "(19561958)" that I would like to split into "(1956-1958)". The regular expression that I tried is:

```
import re
a = "(19561958)"
re.sub(r"(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)", r"\1-", a)
```

but this returns me "(19561958-)". How can I achieve my purpose? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the two years separately, and insert the hyphen between the two groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{4})', r'\1-\2', '(19561958)')
'(1956-1958)'
```

Note that `\d\d\d\d` is written more concisely as `\d{4}`.

---

As currently written, this will insert a hyphen between the first two groups of four in *any* eight-digit-plus number. If you *require* the parentheses for the match, you can include them explicitly with look-arounds:

```
>>> re.sub(r'''
    (?<=\() # make sure there's an opening parenthesis prior to the groups
    (\d{4}) # one group of four digits
    (\d{4}) # and a second group of four digits
    (?=\))  # with a closing parenthesis after the two groups 
''', r'\1-\2', '(19561958)', flags=re.VERBOSE)
'(1956-1958)'
```

Alternatively, you could use word boundaries, which would also deal with e.g. spaces around an eight-digit number:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d{4})(\d{4})\b', r'\1-\2', '(19561958)')
'(1956-1958)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use capturing groups or look arounds.

```
re.sub(r"\((\d{4})(\d{4})\)", r"(\1-\2)", a)
```

`\d{4}` matches exactly 4 digits.

**Example:**

```
>>> a = "(19561958)"
>>> re.sub(r"\((\d{4})(\d{4})\)", r"(\1-\2)", a)
'(1956-1958)'
```

OR

Through lookarounds.

```
>>> a = "(19561958)"
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\(\d{4})(?=\d{4}\))", r"-", a)
'(1956-1958)'
```

- `(?<=\(\d{4})` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by `(` and  four digit characters.
- `(?=\d{4}\))` Posiitve lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by 4 digits plus `)` symbol.
- Here a boundary got matched. Replacing the matched boundary with `-` will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Use two capturing groups: `r"(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)"` or `r"(\d{4})(\d{4})"`.

The 2nd group is referenced with `\2`.